# nginx and uwsgi config issues

Tags: nginx, uwsgi

when using uwsgi with the uwsgi-file parameter, I can see the correctly rendered page at 127.0.0.1/hello.py:

```
plugin = python3
master = true
processes = 5
chdir = /var/www/web1/
http = 127.0.0.1:9090
wsgi-file = /var/www/web1/hello.py
stats = 127.0.0.1:9191
chmod-socket = 777
vacuum = true
enable-threads  = true
die-on-term = true
```

but when i reverse proxy from nginx using

```
location ~ \.py$ {
    try_files $uri /index.py =404;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9090;
    include uwsgi_params;
}
```

and disable the uwsgi-file parameter:

```
plugin = python3
master = true
processes = 5
chdir = /var/www/web1/
http = 127.0.0.1:9090
#wsgi-file = /var/www/web1/hello.py
stats = 127.0.0.1:9191
chmod-socket = 777
vacuum = true
enable-threads  = true
die-on-term = true
```

then I get these errors:

browser - "Internal Server Error"

nginx console - "GET /hello.py HTTP/1.1" 500 32

uwsgi console - "GET /hello.py => generated 21 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.0 500) 2 headers in 83 bytes (0 switches on core 0)"

can I have some help troubleshooting this please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution requires uWSGI run CGI scripts:

1. enable the CGI plugin and configure uwsgi *ini* file as per

[Running CGI scripts on uWSGI](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/CGI.html)

2. configure nginx reverse proxy with the **uwsgi_modifier1 9** parameter

```
location ~ \.py$ {
        try_files $uri /index.py =404;
        uwsgi_modifier1 9;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9090;
        include uwsgi_params;
    }
```

and this type of 'hello world' test:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print "<h1>Hello World</h1>"
```